# datepicker and jsp, issues to get value

Tags: jquery, jsp, datepicker

I have a datepicker element to which I am assigning a date from jsp, previously this was done with a new Date on an input type date, but I must change it with the jquery datepicker for compatibility with ie.

The problem is that when you get the value of the field with jquery. it returns "//" without any date inside.

this is the code:

```
<form:input path="fechaAntSis" id="fechaAntSis" type="hidden" />
<div class="custom-select">
    <input type="text" id="fechaResolucion" data-date-format ="mm/dd/aaaa">
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $( "#fechaResolucion" ).datepicker();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

this return //

```
console.log('inputFecha', $('#fechaAntSis').val());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, add the following code inside: `

```
<head>.. 
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <script>
      $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
      } );
      </script>
</head>
```

Secondly, change the input line to:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

For more information, check this [link](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)